# I am trying to create signup pages in react website but it's not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a signup and sign in new site that's a react site.

I added components navbar/header in that header. I added a login button.

[image: login button]

and the link is working after clicking the link, the page is opening

[image: login page url]

The page's content is not showing. I added css also for content but it's not showing.

ChatGPT is giving answers but my compiler is showing errors. Can anyone of you help me to create this?

I am expecting a signup and login feature website.

This is my app.js code

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";

function App() {
  return(
    
    <Header />
    
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is my `Header.js` code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Login from "../pages/Login";

function Header() {
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);

    const openNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav);
    }
    return (
      <div className="header-container">
        <div className="left-header">
          <h2 className="header">Fallen</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="right-header">
          <Link onClick={openNav} to="/Login">SignUp/Login</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Header;
```

This is my `login js` code:

```
function Login() {
    return(
        <>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        </>
    );
}
export default Login;
```

This is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined routes. After importing ***Routes*** and ***Route*** you should do:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        .
        . 
        .
      </Routes>
    </div>  
  );
}
export default App;
```

***NOTE***: I didn't add the Header because you can add it according to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable routing for your application.

There are two ways to do this, using either 'BrowserRouter' component or 'createBrowserRouter' function.

Way 1: If you going to use 'BrowserRouter' component for routing, setup up your index.js like this way:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="Login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Way 2: The recommended router for all React Router web projects is using 'createBrowserRouter' function, follow the following method to setup routing in your index.js using 'createBrowserRouter'.

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />
  },
  {
    path: "Login",
    element: <Login />
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

I tested the solution.
You can refer it here: [routing solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-matsumoto-lrffk2?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

If this is your problem then you have to first import some of the components from react-router-dom that is available in the latest version of it. And you should update your App.js like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>  
  );
}
export default App;
```

Now this will create your route for the login and signup page.
May this will help you.